# PHP regular expression help

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I am using preg_replace to strip out `<p>` tags and `<li>` tags and making them carriage returns.  I have some `<a`> tags in my string, and I want to strip those out, but keep the href attribute.  For instance, if I have:
    `<a href = "http://www.example.com">Click Here</a>`, what I want is:    `http://www.example.com` Click Here

Here is what I have so far

```
$text .= preg_replace(array("/<p[^>]*>/iU","/<\/p[^>]*>/iU","/<ul[^>]*>/iU","/<\/ul[^>]*>/iU","/<li[^>]*>/iU","/<\/li[^>]*>/iU"), array("","\r\n\r\n","","\r\n\r\n","","\r\n"), $content);
```

Thanks

Comment: Your life would probably be much easier if you used an HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I would use [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Here's a usage example from the docs:

```
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html; 
// Output: <div id="hello">foo</div><div id="world" class="bar">World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a regex solution is desired, here is a tested function which handles the anchor tags as you requested (with notable caveats noted below.) The regex is presented in verbose mode with comments:

```php
function process_markup($content) {
    return preg_replace(
        array( // Regex patterns
            '%<(?:p|ul|li)[^>]*>%i',        // Open tags.
            '%<\/(?:p|ul|li)[^>]*>\s*%i',   // Close tags.
            '% # Match A element (with no "<>" in attributes!)
            <a\b         # Start tag name.
            [^>]+?       # anything up to HREF attribute.
            href\s*=\s*  # HREF attribute name and "="
            (["\']?)     # $1: Optional quote delimiter
            ([^>\s]+)    # $2: HREF attribute value.
            (?(1)\1)     # If open quote, match close quote.
            [^>]*>       # Remainder of start tag
            (.*?)        # $3: A element contents.
            </a\s*>      # A element end tag.
            %ix'
        ),
        array( // Replacement strings
            "",          # Simply strip P, UL, and LI open tags.
            "\r\n",      # Replace close tags with line endings.
            "$2 $3"      # Keep A element HREF value and contents.
        ), $content);
}
```

I took the liberty of modifying the other regexes as well. Adjust as necessary.

**CAVEATS:** This regex solution assumes: All `A`, `P`, `UL` and `LI` elements have no angle brackets `<>`in their attributes. There are no `A`, `P`, `UL` or `LI` element start or end tags within any `CDATA` sections such as `SCRIPT` or `STYLE` elements, or HTML comments, or inside other start tag attributes. Otherwise, this should work pretty well for a lot of HTML markup.

I realize that many wince when they hear the words: `HTML` and `REGEX` spoken in the same breath, but in this particular case, I think a regex solution will work quite well (within the above limitations). The `A` tag is one of those which is *not nested*, so a regex can easily match the start tag, contents and end tag all in one whack. Same thing with the individual start and end tags for the other elements (which *can* be nested) when considered independently.